# move a Folder in Pentaho

Tags: rest, pentaho

I am new to Pentaho and I am trying using REST API to change a folder path with all his content, to move a folder from a location to an other location
Example
We have this structure
mainFolder
|
- subFolder1
|
- subFolder2
|
-subSubFolder

And after a rest call I am trying to have this structure:
mainFolder
|
-subFolder1
|
- subFolder2
|
- subSubFolder

The folder "subSubFolder" is on the same level as subFolder1 and subFolder2.

Can anyone help me how I can do this with REST API calls ? I am still searching for the REST URL to delete a folder and for moving a folder I found nothing.

Thank you,
Adi

Comment: What kind of files are you trying to move? Pentaho has several products.